# If user related data is encrypted, how can you perform searches on these columns?

Tags: sql-server, encryption

If I have a users table of 1 million users, and if for security compliance reasons I have to encrypt the firstname, lastname and email address of the users, how can I possible provide a search feature?

When the data is encrypted and stored in a `varbinary` column type, how can I allow users of my application to search for users based on partial matches of firstname, lastname and email address?

If I have to decrypt the entire database to perform the query, this will not be practical when there are 1 million users in our database.

Comment: If you must encrypt names, then allowing searches on names should not be allowed either, because by brute force you can discover all names using search,

Answer (score 0):

I think that's the whole point of encryption. If I can be easily reversed, then it is not doing its job.

I assume your encryption would most likely involve a salt field. If that's the case, chances are you have very little options.

Answer (score 0):

Create a column to store a hash (eg SHA256) of the name plus a (constant) salt, then search for the hash of the searched-for name (plus the salt).

Note that only exact matches can be found, plus there’s a security risk in not using a user-variable salt that hashes of common names will appear multiple times and an attacker could use this to divine the names without even decrypting the data.

Answer (score 0):

The data for 1 million users is quite small by today’s standards - way under a gig. You could just load the entire DB into memory on startup of your application and use a reverse index on all names, possibly under an ordered map to allow prefix search too, or use an in-memory NoSQL (eg Lucene) to do the heavy lifting.

Although it would take a several seconds to load the data, lookups would be lighting fast - way fast enough to put behind a suggest-as-you-type input box.